# Can I check whether any deployed contract has implemented some particular interface or not?

Tags: solidity, go-ethereum, blockchain, remix, solidity-0.6.x

My concern is whether I can do interface detection with my own interface,,, 
Like suppose, i have implemented some interface say `loyalty interface` in my one contract and I have deployed that contract ,, can i check in my another contract using the previous contract's contract address whether that has implemented `loyalty interface` interface or not ?

Comment: On-chain, you can use `staticcall` and see if it has succeeded or not (using assembly if you're on solc 0.4 or lower, and solidity if you're on solc 0.5 or higher). Off-chain, you can read the contract's bytecode and check if the function-selector (first 4 bytes in the hash of the function signature) is included in that bytecode.

Comment: The on-chain method above is of course useful only for constant (`pure` or `view`) functions.